# How can I edit or extend the error message in laravel5.3?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to extend validation setting another field just like that:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    'another_field' => 'validation'
]);
```

Comment: Ok thanks for editing.Must be helpful to ask further question.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your own validation case by follwing the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules) :)

Comment: Great but I need more specific one or any other document.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: you can find [here] (https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/custom-validation-function-in-laravel-5/replies/152118) a full code example i think it will work for 5.3 too

Comment: if it didn't work tell me, so we can find another way

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the message only, you can do it by

```
$messages = [
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
    'email' => 'This is a wrong e-mail address message I wrote myself.',
];

$rules = [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    'another_field' => 'validation'
];

return Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```